# "Aquiescer" resolve o duplo sentido da "Condescendência"?

Tags: uso-de-palavras, palavra-para-ideia

Vi um Inglês usar o verbo ["acquiesce"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/acquiesce) e achei super elegante. A palavra "soou-me" familiar, por tudo, cada letra, sílaba, morfema. Foi com e sem surpresa, que descobri existir [a mesmíssima palavra em Português](https://dicionario.priberam.org/aquiesce), com origem no latim é claro.

Então a minha primeira pergunta é se alguma vez leram ou ouviram a palavra "aquiescer"? Eu nunca tinha visto tal vocábulo...

Depois, o "condescender" é palavra que evito (como podem ver na citação) tem um **duplo sentido plenamente contraditório**. **Um antítese-vocábulo, um paradoxo semântico**. (Em Inglês vejo o adjectivo ser usado quase sempre com conotação negativa, e o verbo mais vezes com conotação positiva.) Vocês usariam esta palavra como? E usam-na?

Por fim, estou um bocado cansado do transigente/intransigente; deferir/indeferir. O último par é mais burocrático, o primeiro pessoal.

Mas aparte o ["obtemperar"](https://dicionario.priberam.org/obtemperar) (que acabei de descobrir, acho encantador, mas impossível de ser usado no quotidiano) não encontro uma palavra alternativa ao par ceder/aceder que seja pura virtude da mansidão e humildade, no sentido de tornar a concórdia um bem, e força de uma aparente fraqueza.

Alternativas (no sentido deste último parágrafo)?

> con·des·cen·dên·ci·a
>
> (condescender + -ência)
>
> substantivo feminino
>
> 1. Acção de condescender.
> 2. Qualidade do que é condescendente.
> 3. Flexibilidade de carácter que se acomoda ao gosto e vontade doutros.
> 4. Deferência.
> 5. Indulgência, transigência.
> 6. Superioridade arrogante ou paternalista em relação a algo ou alguém.
>
> ["condescendência", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa](https://dicionario.priberam.org/condescend%C3%AAncia), 2008-2020, [consultado em 09-02-2020].

Comment: Não deves [misturar várias perguntas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts) na mesma Pergunta.

Comment: Para clarificar, a pergunta do título é se "aquiescer" resolve o duplo sentido de "condescender", as restantes perguntas convidam a elaborar sobre o espaço semântico de sinonímia que rodeia as palavras, acho ser necessário para um resposta que seja significativa, tanto convergente como abrangente. O conjunto das perguntas forma um todo coerente, cujas partes não são independentes entre sí, nem devem ser tomadas como tal. É uma visão "de conjunto", no espaço dos possiveis.

Comment: Você é de Portugal? No Brasil "aquiescer" é muito comum na língua escrita (na fala é raro). "Condescendente" nunca vi ser usada em sentido positivo.

Comment: A primeira (e única) vez que vi a palavra "aquiescer" em uso foi na versão dublada do primeiro filme da série *Piratas do Caribe* onde, em certo momento, o Capitão Barbosa diz para Elizabeth: **Estou desinclinado a aquiescer a sua solicitação**. (Diga-se de passagem, essa foi também a primeira vez que vi o uso da palavra "desinclinado".)

Answer (score 1):

> Então a minha primeira pergunta é se alguma vez leram ou ouviram a palavra "aquiescer"? Eu nunca tinha visto tal vocábulo...

Sim, já vi essa palavra muitas vezes, embora talvez com maior frequência em traduções para o português de obras originalmente em inglês.

> "condescender" [...] Vocês usariam esta palavra como? E usam-na?

Uso tanto em português quanto inglês, sempre com sentido negativo.

> palavra alternativa ao par ceder/aceder [...] Alternativas?

Se entendi corretamente a pergunta, possibilidades incluem:
*anuir, assentir, concordar, consentir, aprovar, aceitar, permitir, autorizar*.

"Anuir", em particular, tem o antônimo "[abnuir](https://dicionario.priberam.org/abnuir)" (que também acabo de 'descobrir').

Comment: Boa resposta @stafusa! Vou precisar de algum tempo para ver cada palavra e pensar no conjunto dos sentidos. Depois respondo aqui em comentário. (P.S. Achei o antónimo abnuir genial !!)